# Scala: use def or val when instantiating from a trait?

Tags: scala

I'm reading *Functional Programming in Scala* by Chiusano and Bjarnason.

In Chapter 10, they define the `Monoid` trait:

```
trait Monoid[A] {
    def op(a1: A, a2: A): A
    def zero: A
}
```

Two example instances of the trait are the following:

1) `String` Monoid:

```
val stringMonoid = new Monoid[String] {
    def op(a1: String, a2: String) = a1 + a2
    val zero = ""
}
```

2) `List` Monoid:

```
def listMonoid[A] = new Monoid[List[A]] {
    def op(a1: List[A], a2: List[A]) = a1 ++ a2
    val zero = Nil
}
```

My question is, why do we use `val` in the case of `stringMonoid`, and `def` in `listMonoid`?

Comment: `listMonoid` takes a type parameter `[A]` which isn't permitted for a `val` (syntax error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringMonoid` is a string type `new Monoid[String]`

`listMonoid` is a generic type `new Monoid[List[A]]`. To pass this generic type `A` it is declared as `def`

```
def listMonoid[A] = new Monoid[List[A]]
```

**Edit**

To address the comment:

If you still want is to use `val` for `listMonoid`, then define what list is going to have in it.

```
val listMonoid = new Monoid[List[Int]] {
  def op(a1: List[Int], a2: List[Int]) = a1 ++ a2
  def zero = List.empty
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. What would be the right way to use `listMonoid` then?

Comment: @cwl `listMonoid[String].zero` should work. Ultimately, you'll probably want implicits, and maybe [Simulacrum](https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum).